# How to manage an offline Mongo Database in Android

Tags: android, mongodb, android-studio, express, offline-mode

I want to make an android APP that can be used totally without internet (being able to insert new entries, see the old ones, delete them, modify them, etc), I would use a backend in nodejs with express and MongoDB. 
I have seen that it could be done by relying on local SQLite when there is no internet access. 
But I would like to know if there is a better way to do this with the stack I am going to do the APP.

I will use Android 9 (API 28)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Realm](https://realm.io/). This will give you a mobile database with syncing to MongoDB on the roadmap.